# Does MySQL intend to have new users added to the mysql user table?

Tags: mysql

Is the mysql user table intended to store all user accounts for all databases or should a separate table be made inside the database being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql.user` table is for the accounts which can access the mysql server. This table is not for your application working with the mysql server to save their website users.

Comment: Would a generic user need to be created in the mysql.user table for the initial db connection? For example, new PDO object(host, db, username, password). Would this be populated with the generic username and password?

Comment: @csell Yes, the `mysql.user` table controls who can access/enter the mysql server. When you want your PHP script to login into your MySQL server you need to add an account in that table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-account-management.html

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help and clarification!